# Remove certain circles in toc of beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I want to remove only one section circle in the toc of beamer. But I don't know how to do it. Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[14pt,c]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[circle]

\begin{document}

\frame[plain,c,noframenumbering]{
 \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]}

\section{section 1}

    \frame{ frame 1}

\section{section 2}

    \frame{ frame 2}

\section{lastsection} %which I want to remove its prefix circle or number in toc.

    \frame{frame 3}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing just the number is easy: you can specify the last numbered section in the toc with `lastsection=2`

Removing the circle as well is a bit trickier, but you can redefine the `section in toc` template like this:

```
\documentclass[14pt,c]{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}
{\leavevmode\leftskip=2ex%
  \llap{%
    \ifnum\beamer@tempcount>\beamer@toclastsection
    \else
    \usebeamerfont*{section number projected}%
    \usebeamercolor{section number projected}%
    \begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{0ex}{1ex}{2ex}
      \color{bg}
      \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0pt}{.75ex}}{1.2ex}
      \pgfusepath{fill}
      \pgftext[base]{\color{fg}\inserttocsectionnumber}
    \end{pgfpicture}\kern1.25ex%
    \fi
  }%
  \inserttocsection\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frame[plain,c,noframenumbering]{
 \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections,lastsection=2]}

\section{section 1}

    \frame{ frame 1}

\section{section 2}

    \frame{ frame 2}


\section{lastsection} %which I want to remove its prefix circle or number in toc.

    \frame{frame 3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works for me. Another question. Can we let latex do the 'lastsection=2' automatically?

Comment: @MiGang How should latex know how many numbered sections you want?